# Bugzilla LDAP Configuration

Tags: windows-7, bugzilla

In Bugzilla all the parameters are working for me but LDAP alone not synchronizing with my AD Server. can you give me the steps to configure LDAP in Bugzilla 4.6.6 on Windows 7. Eg my server is located in our office premises and we are using as

```
LDAPServer -> Hp-02.company.local
Basedn -> CN=Users,DC=Company,Dc=local
Binddn -> i did not assign any thing in this.
LdapUidattribute -> uid
Ldapmailattribute -> mail
LdapFilter -> (ObjectClass=*)
```

This is enough for the Configuration or to made any changes for this or any PPM module to be install or I need to create a LDAP user and password in my Active Directory.

Kindly help me...

Answer (score 2):

Active Directory (AD) doesn't allow anonymous binds by default (sensibly, to my mind). Per the [Bugzilla documentation](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/parameters.html#bzldap) leaving the `LDAPbinddn` parameter causes Bugzilla to attempt to perform anonymous binds. This is going to fail. (I'd advise reading about [LDAP searches in Active Directory](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755809%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to give you some more background on the process. It's worth understanding what's going on behind the scenes.)

You will need to create a user in your AD for Bugzilla to bind with when it performs authentication. The user doesn't have to be privileged (a normal "Domain User" will do-- and, in fact, is preferred).

If this is a deal breaker consider using [RADIUS authentication](http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.4/en/html/parameters.html#bzradius) with Microsoft's RADIUS server. You won't need to create a user account in your AD for this method to work. You will, obviously, have to install and configure either [Network Policy Server or Internet Authentication Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892033%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (depending on the server's Windows version).

Comment: Using my Account i am able to login into AD,can i user my username and password in LDAPBinddn For example(cn=arun.p,cn=arun.p:abc123)             or i need to do any other changes in my Configuration,LDAP filter is mandatory or not,if mandatory above is correct or not.